# Multi Site Magento store won't reimport a CSV of products that I just exported

Tags: product, configurable-product, import, csv, export

I have two different sites for my magento store. Each site is originated in a different country. I am trying to create a configurable product with attributes such as colour and size. These attributes if they are set will have prices attached to them.

Ex:

- color -> Red   -> 5$
- color -> Black -> 10$
- size  -> Small -> 20$
- size  -> Large -> 30$

That would be the prices for one of the sites on those attributes. Then on the other site I would like to increase the prices on the color's. I can complete this using the magento admin panel and it works.

I would like to create it through importing a CSV. So I exported the working product through CSV then I deleted the product through the admin panel. Then I try to import the CSV back into the magento admin panel but I get the error "Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows" for all the _super_products_sku. This is because when I exported the product all the simple products were listed after the configurable product. I then switch the position of them and I don't get any errors when I check the data. But the item doesn't function as intended. Only some of the configurations show up and the prices for the different attributes are the same for both sites.

I can't upload the CSV's so if you would like to see them I can put them in a dropbox link and send them.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please make the CSV available? In general, it works with Mage_ImportExport, see the slides by Vinai Kopp about importing configurable products at http://netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you edit your CSV with Excel?

They have the bad habit of auto-formatting numeric values. So if you have some SKUs starting with one or multiple `0`, there is a chance Excel stripped those zeros. Which would explain why you are getting the `Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows` message.

Comment: Yeah thats what I originally thought but the sku's in magento don't have a zero on them when i import them the second way.